# galleria jquery plugin slow with lots of images

Tags: jquery, galleria

Has anyone extended the galleria plugin to handle lots of images (over 200)?  The large number of thumbnails makes the initial load take a really long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use separate thumbnail files and option [preload](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/options/preload/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm already using separate thumbnail files, and with 500 thumbnails the initial page load still takes a really long time.  The preload option default is 2 so I don't think loading those two images is causing the problem.  I imagine all that time is being spent creating those 500 dom elements and attaching events to them.  It would be nice if the plugin created a window of 50 or so thumbnails and then built the dom/events as the user paged through the carousel, to improve initial responsiveness.  Btw, I'm using a json datasource.

Comment: Do you reaaly need 500 images in your galleria? Try to reduce images in slideshow or... modify galleria somehow :) I made some updates in galleria earlier for one of my projects. Code is clear enough.